# Como criar um "template" para páginas?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, template

Sou novo em desenvolvimento de sites, programação, etc, minha praia é o Design, mas gostaria de saber como vocês fazem quando precisam repetir algum layout em **todas as páginas do site.**

> Por exemplo: preciso repetir esse menu em todas as páginas do site. Eu
>   copio o HTML dele e colo em todas as páginas que preciso? Ou existe outra maneira mais
>   prática?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: so usando HTML puro(sem js ou server side) nao tem como reutilizar. Agora com js ou alguma liguagem server side fica facil, da uma lida no topico que o bacco passou que tem varias dicas.

Comment: @NeuberOliveira Pode crer, eu dei uma olhada. Não to usando nenhum server side, só HTML puro. No caso a reutilização se chama "include"?

Answer (score 0):

**Não sei nada de PHP**, mas já li um pouco sobre reutilizar partes do sites em outros página.

Um site é dividido em Topo, miolo e rodapé. As partes que mais repetem em toda as página são o topo e o rodapé.

Então os desenvolvedores separam o código de uma parte que irá se repetir durante todas as páginas e colocam em outro arquivo. Eles incluem com `<?php include('includes/topo.php');?>`

Para fazer isso vc terá que renomear o seu arquivo principal .html para .php e separar esse sidebar como disse a cima. Se seguir esse caminho terá também que usar um servidor apache.

Answer (score 0):

Isso é uma pergunta muito abrangente! Existe diversas formas.

Em PHP, ASP, C# e demais linguagens:

- Criar Includes
- Carregamento via ajax

em frameworks javascript:

- Angular
- Ionic
- Laravel

Todos você pode trabalhar com templates. Não dá pra detalhar muito, pois é extenso demais o assunto, mais se você buscar por templates nesses frameworks no youtube você encontrará muito material bacana.